# updating dictionary dose not work in the loop

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

```
H=0
 R=0
 C=0
 His=0
 Adv=0
 A=0
dic_of_genres={"Horror":H,"Romance":R,"Comedy":C,"History":His,"Adventure":Adv,"Action":A}
n=int(input())
for i in range(0,n):
    x=input().split()
    print(x)
    for items in x:
        if items =='Horror':
            H=H+1
        elif items =='Romance':
            R+=1
        elif items =="Comedy":
            C+=1
        elif items =="History":
            His+=1
        elif items =="Adventure":
            Adv+=1
        elif items =="Action":
            A+=1
print(dic_of_genres) `
```

I can not understand why my dictionary doesn't update in each loop. Could any body help me?

Comment: Because your variables are not mutable. You need to use the dictionary to update the values `dic_of_genres["Horror"] += 1`

Comment: could you please help me more? I am new in python.

Comment: @Ali check the edited version. It had a small bug

Comment: @Nuri Taş, could you help me with my last task as well? The question is after your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to go over each item. Note that I also added a `try except` in case `x` have different elements than `dic_of_genres`

```
for i in range(0,n):
    x= [item.capitalize() for item in input().split()]
    for genre in set(x):
               try:
                     dic_of_genres[genre] += x.count(genre)
               except KeyError:
                     pass

print(dic_of_genres)
```

Comment: @ Guy, I want to print the result like:  Action=1 \n, Adventure =1 \n , ....This means that I want to sort them by highest score then in alphabet if the score is the same in different line. I use sorted(dic_of_genres.items(),key=lambda,x:(x[0],x[1]). How I can print them without bracket and comma in separated line?